# Why is the size of the data type different when the value is directly passed to the sizeof operator?

Tags: c, int, sizeof

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a = 'A';
    int b = 90000;
    float c = 6.5;
    printf("%d ",sizeof(6.5));
    printf("%d ",sizeof(90000));
    printf("%d ",sizeof('A'));
    printf("%d ",sizeof(c));
    printf("%d ",sizeof(b));
    printf("%d",sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
8 4 4 4 4 1
```

Why is the output different for the same values?

Comment: `6.5` is not a float, it's a `double`

Comment: `printf("%d",sizeof(6.5f));` to make it a `float`.

Comment: "why the output is differen0t here?" why it should be the same? The fact that you can assign one to another does not mean they have exactly the same type.

Comment: The format specifier should be, for example, `printf("%zu", sizeof(6.5));`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Character constants in C (opposite to C++) have the type `int`. So this call

```
printf("%d",sizeof('A'));
```

outputs 4. That is `sizeof( 'A' )` is equal to `sizeof( int )`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.4 Character constants)

> 10 **An integer character constant has type int**....

On the other hand (6.5.3.4  The sizeof and alignof operators)

> 4 When sizeof is applied to an operand that has type char, unsigned
>   char, or signed char, (or a qualiﬁed version thereof) the result is 1.

So the operand of the `sizeof` operator in this expression `sizeof( 'A' )` has the type int while in this expression `sizeof( a )` where a is declared like

```
char a = 'A';
```

the operand has the type `char`.

Pay attention to that calls like this

```
printf("%d",sizeof(6.5));
```

use incorrect conversion format specifier. You have to write

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(6.5));
```

Also in the above call there is used a constant of the type `double` while in this call

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(c));
```

the variable `c` has the type `float`.

You could get the same result for these calls if the first call used a constant of the type float like

```
printf("%zu",sizeof(6.5f));
```

Answer (score 18):

Constants, like variables, have a type of their own:

- `6.5`   : A floating point constant of type `double`
- `90000` : An integer constant of type `int` (if `int` is 32 bits) or `long` (if `int` is 16 bits)
- `'A'`   : A character constant of type `int` in C and `char` in C++

The sizes that are printed are the sizes of the above types.

Also, the result of the `sizeof` operator has type `size_t`.  So when printing the proper format specifier to use is `%zu`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the values don't matter to `sizeof`. It's the size of the types.

- character constants are `int`s, not `char`s.
- floating-point constants are by default `double`s unless you suffix them with `f` or `l`.